# Using base Images for Services in docker-compose with different args

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

**My Setup:**
I have 3 Services defined in my `docker-compose.yml`: `frontend` `backend` and `postgresql`. `postgresql` is pulled from docker-hub.

`frontend` and `backend` are built from their own Dockerfiles, most of the Code of these Dockerfiles is the same and only `EXPOSE` `ENTRPOINT` `CMD` and `ARG`-Values differ from each other. That is why I wanted to create a 'base-Dockerfile' that these two Services can "include". 
Sadly I found out I can not simply "include" a Dockerfile into another Dockerfile, I have to create an Image. 
So I tried to create a base image for `frontend` and `backend` in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  frontend_base:
    image: frontend_base_image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: base.dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=/app/frontend/
        - TOOLSDIR=${PWD}/docker/tools
        - LOCALDIR=${PWD}/app/frontend/client

  backend_base:
    image: backend_base_image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: base.dockerfile
      args:
        - WORKDIR=/app/backend/
        - TOOLSDIR=${PWD}/docker/tools
        - LOCALDIR=${PWD}/app/backend/api

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - frontend_base
    # Some more stuff for the service
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - backend_base
    # Some more stuff for the service
```

My 'base-Dockerfile':

```dockerfile
FROM node:18

# Set in docker-compose.yml-file
ARG WORKDIR
ARG TOOLSDIR
ARG LOCALDIR
ENV WORKDIR=${WORKDIR}

# Install dumb-init for the init system
RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/dumb-init https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.5/dumb-init_1.2.5_x86_64
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}

# Copy package.json to the current workdir (for npm install)
COPY ${LOCALDIR}/package*.json ${WORKDIR}

# Install all Packages (refereed from package.json)
RUN npm install

COPY ${TOOLSDIR}/start.sh /usr/local/bin/start.sh
COPY ${LOCALDIR}/ ${WORKDIR}
```

**The Problem I am facing:**
My `frontend` and `backend` Dockerfiles try to pull the 'base-image' from docker.io

```shell
 => ERROR [docker-backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/backend_base_image:latest                                                                                 0.9s
 => ERROR [docker-frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/frontend_base_image:latest                                                                               0.9s
 => CANCELED [frontend_base_image internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18
```

**My Research:**
I do not know if my approach is possible, I did not find much Resources about this (integrated with docker-compose) online, only Resources about building the Images via Shell and then using them in a Dockerfile. I also tried this and ran into some other issues, where I could not provide correct arguments to the base-Dockerfile.
So I firstly wanted to find out if it is possible with docker-compose.

I am sorry if this is super obvious and my Question is dumb, I am relatively new to Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use the feature of a [multistage containerfile](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) to define all three images in a single containerfile:

```
FROM node:18 AS base

# Set in docker-compose.yml-file
ARG WORKDIR
ARG TOOLSDIR
ARG LOCALDIR
ENV WORKDIR=${WORKDIR}

# Install dumb-init for the init system
RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/dumb-init https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.5/dumb-init_1.2.5_x86_64
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}

# Copy package.json to the current workdir (for npm install)
COPY ${LOCALDIR}/package*.json ${WORKDIR}

# Install all Packages (refereed from package.json)
RUN npm install

COPY ${TOOLSDIR}/start.sh /usr/local/bin/start.sh
COPY ${LOCALDIR}/ ${WORKDIR}

FROM base AS frontend
...

FROM base AS backend
...
```

In our `docker-compose.yml`, we can then [build a specific stage](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#target) for the `frontend`- and `backend`-service:

```
  ...
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: ./
      target: frontend
      dockerfile: base.dockerfile
    ...
  backend:
    image: backend
    build:
      context: ./
      target: backend
      dockerfile: base.dockerfile
    ...
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestions, but now I cannot `COPY` Local files, it seems like Docker wants to search for the Files in a 'buildkit-mount'-Directory. 
`ERROR [docker-frontend base 6/9] COPY ./../app/frontend/client/package*.json /app/frontend/`
`failed to solve: lstat /home/toni/.local/share/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3952014366/app/frontend/client: no such file or directory`

Comment: Have you set the `args` of the containers correctly?

Comment: Yes I have copied the `args` from the original `docker-compose.yml` `backend_base` and `frontend_base` (see Question). I also tried it with a relative Path and an absolute Path, using `${PWD}`

Comment: Do you have  a [MRE]? Preferrable in form of a git repo?

Comment: Hmm... why is there a `..` in the path? From a containerfile, we cannot "break out" of the build context, i.e. `..` is a no-no. Also, paths in a `COPY` should always be relative

Comment: Here is the mre: https://gitlab.com/purpys/mre-stackoverflow-q-75190415
Oh sorry, the Error Message was from when I used a relative Path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251296/discussion-between-turing85-and-toni).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single base image with shared tools, you can do this almost exactly the way you describe; but the one caveat is that you can't describe the base image in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  You need to run separately from Compose

```bash
docker build -t base-image -f base.dockerfile .
```

I would not try to install any application code in that base Dockerfile.  Where you for example install an `init` wrapper that needs to be shared across all of your application images, that does make sense.  I think it's fine to tie a Dockerfile to a specific source-tree and image layout, and don't typically recommend passing filesystem paths as `ARG`s.

```bash
# base.dockerfile
FROM node:18

RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/dumb-init https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.5/dumb-init_1.2.5_x86_64 \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

COPY docker/tools/start.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["start.sh"]
```

The per-image Dockerfiles will look pretty similar – and like every other Node Dockerfile – but there's no harm in repeating this, in much the same way that your components probably have similar-looking but self-contained `package.json` files.

```bash
# */Dockerfile
FROM base-image

WORKDIR /app  # also creates it
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm build

EXPOSE 3000
# CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]  # if the start.sh from the base is wrong
```

Of note, this gives you some flexibility to change things if the two image setups aren't *identical*; if you need an additional build step, or if you want to run a dev server, or package the frontend into a lighter-weight Nginx server.

In the Compose file you'd declare these normally with a `build:` block.  Compose isn't aware of the base image and there's no way to tell it about it.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./app/frontend/client
    ports: ['3000:3000']
  backend:
    build: ./app/backend/api
    ports: ['3001:3000']
```

One thing I've done here which at least reduces the number of variable references is to consistently use `.` as the current directory name.  In the Compose file that's the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml`; on the left-hand side of `COPY` it's the `build:` context directory on the host; on the right-hand side of `COPY` it's the most recent `WORKDIR`.  Using `.` where appropriate means you don't have to repeat the directory name, so you do have a little flexibility if you do need to rearrange your source tree or container filesystem.